# How to donwload a div's content as a JPEG file in nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js

I'm designing a business card generator, but don't know how to download the card. It's a just a simple div.

Is there any way to download this div as JPEG?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, but in its current state, your question might get downvoted or closed. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking so people can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

I did that a while ago, you can use the "html2canvas" npm package. It works so quickly. This is how you can download div's html content into image JPEG format

You can refer to this simple guide, if you need more help and a small example for it: [Convert Div to Image and download](https://ayedot.com/6104/MiniBlog/How-to-Convert--Download-HTML-or-divs-Content-as-Image-in-any-JavaScript-Framework)

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";

const DivToImage = () => {
  const exportDivImageRef: any = useRef();
  const [downloading, setDownloading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const exportAsImage = async (element, imageFileName) => {
    setDownloading(true);
    try {
      const html: any = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
      const body: any = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      let htmlWidth = html.clientWidth;
      let bodyWidth = body.clientWidth;
      const newWidth = element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth;
      if (newWidth > element.clientWidth) {
        htmlWidth += newWidth;
        bodyWidth += newWidth;
      }
      html.style.width = htmlWidth + "px";
      body.style.width = bodyWidth + "px";
      const canvas = await html2canvas(element, {
        allowTaint: true,
        useCORS: true,
      });
      const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
      downloadImage(image, imageFileName);
      html.style.width = null;
      body.style.width = null;
    } catch (error) {
      setDownloading(false);
    }
  };

  const downloadImage = (blob, fileName) => {
    try {
      const fakeLink: any = window.document.createElement("a");
      fakeLink.style = "display:none;";
      fakeLink.download = fileName;

      fakeLink.href = blob;

      document.body.appendChild(fakeLink);
      fakeLink.click();
      document.body.removeChild(fakeLink);

      fakeLink.remove();
      setDownloading(false);
      setDownloading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setDownloading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={exportRef}>
        <h4>Hello world on Image!</h4>
      </div>
      <button onClick={downloadImage}>Download Card Image</button>
    </>
  );
};
```